# Select SEQUENCE in SQL: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, database-sequence

I created a a sequence in SQL:

`CREATE SEQUENCE MYSEQ 
increment by 5
start with 10;`

When I try to select the sequence: 
`select sequence MYSEQ.nextval from DUAL;`

I get the error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `sequence` keyword:

```
select MYSEQ.nextval
from DUAL;
```